# Using LaTeX in plotly 3D axis and tick labels

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Is plotly (v4.5.0) unable to process raw strings into LaTeX for 3D figure axis labels?

For a test, I'm running the code below in a Jupyter notebook. I've intentionally tried a few differing string formats to experiment with how the API handles them. The raw strings generate LaTeX for `title`. But I find no luck for the axis nor tick labels, which are elements of `scene`.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# define time and space data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400)
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 200)
xx, tt = np.meshgrid(x, t)
f1 = 1/np.cosh(xx + 3) * np.exp(1j*2.3*tt)

# visualize
fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(z=np.real(f1), x=xx, y=tt))
fig.update_layout(title=r'$f_1(t)$', 
                  autosize=False, width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=20, r=20, b=20, t=40),
                  scene=dict(xaxis=dict(title=r'x'),
                             yaxis=dict(title=r'$t$')))
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis=dict(nticks=3),
                             yaxis=dict(ticktext=["0",r"\pi",r"$2\pi$","3\pi","4\pi"],
                                        tickvals=np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,5))))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, plotly is unable to do that at the moment. Since 2016, there's an [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/608) open for it at plotly.js repository (on top of which plotly python is built).

From the issue, it seems due to:

> A known limitation of using WebGL for 3D plots.

Answer (score -3):

Its unclear from the description above what you're trying to achieved, but what i understood correctly is you're trying to change the axis label in the surface plot. Here is how you can easily do that.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# define time and space data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400)
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 200)
xx, tt = np.meshgrid(x, t)
f1 = 1/np.cosh(xx + 3) * np.exp(1j*2.3*tt)

# visualize
fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(z=np.real(f1), x=xx, y=tt))
fig.update_layout(title='Plot Title',autosize=True,
                  width=900, height=900, 
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='X-axis Title',
                    yaxis_title='X-axis Title',
                    zaxis_title='X-axis Title'))                    
fig.show()
```

you can also add Contours to surface plot:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# define time and space data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400)
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 200)
xx, tt = np.meshgrid(x, t)
f1 = 1/np.cosh(xx + 3) * np.exp(1j*2.3*tt)

# visualize
fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(z=np.real(f1), x=xx, y=tt))
fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True,
                                  highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True))
fig.update_layout(title='Plot Title',autosize=True,
                  width=900, height=900, 
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='X-axis Title',
                    yaxis_title='Y-axis Title',
                    zaxis_title='Z-axis Title'))                    
fig.show()
```

Here is the output image:
**1.axis-label plot added**
[image: axis-label added]
**2.contour plot added to surface plot**
[image: contour plot added to surface plot]

Comment: Right. I'm asking if you can generate LaTeX axes labels. In other plotting API's, this is often done by passing in a raw string like `r"$X$-axis Title"`. Then the X will be formatted via LaTeX. This didn't work for me in the above example when I originally tried it.